# How can we run Web Server from a Pen Drive without Installation?

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, usb-drive

I have a system with Windows XP Professional and I do not have access to Administrator login. I wish to test some PHP sites however, do not have access to install web servers like IIS, XAMP or WAMP. Is there an alternate to run any such web server from a Pen Drive / Flash Drive.

Comment: When you Google `How can we run Web Server from a Pen Drive without Installation` there is a number of good options. Always remember to do that first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use ubuntu or another linux distro on a bootable USB drive (you have to boot to the USB stick on start-up). You could then install a LAMP stack on the linux OS on pen drive and an IDE. Check it out here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Yip this is the way to go. Skip windows all together.

Answer (score 0):

If you have php 5.4.0 or above available on your computer, you can run a simple webserver like this from command line

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, as I said I just have windows with no admin priviledge. Nothing related to web is installed, No PHP, no MySql

Comment: @HybridSolutions You can download PHP in a .zip, with no installation required. Get it here: http://windows.php.net/download/ Click the "zip" download link - it should be the top one.